# Google Closure Compiler Includes

Tags: javascript, requirejs, google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library

I've been using google closure compiler for a little bit with my projects, it's awesome!

I've been trying to find out whether or not you can do "includes" in a javascript file that includes other javascript files. I'm trying to have 1 javascript file that "includes" all the files I need then compiles, much like you can do with a LESS import statement, ("@import "../less/bootstrap") for example.

Is this possible? - Or do you have to provide the list of source files at time of compilation in the command line?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## When Using Closure-Library

"Includes" are handled via goog.require calls. See https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/tutorial#zippy

In un-compiled code, the included scripts are dynamically inserted. During compilation, the compiler will include all the necessary scripts and dead-code elimination will remove the unused methods and symbols.

## Other Options

The most popular option for handling JavaScript includes/dependencies is [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). RequireJS does dynamic script insertion. Closure-compiler has a Common JS pass which translates RequireJS `require` calls to `goog.require` calls so that the compiler can then include them directly during compilation.

Comment: Not using closure-library, mainly angular / jquery

Comment: @BenKilah added other options.

Comment: Even if you aren't using any other part of Closure Library you can still use goog.provide/goog.require to manage dependencies.